# Opening multiple types quickly with ReSharper

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, resharper

There is an 'open type' feature that supports wild card searching, and it would be very convenient to be able to open several in the list at once rather than running the same command n times in order to get the desired behavior.  I need something better than using the solution explorer given that the types I'm searching for could be scattered across many projects/folders.

Is there a way to achieve this using Visual Studio 2010 and ReSharper (or other tools, if its impossible given my dev environment)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the little icon on the upper right and move the results to the "Show in Find Results" and then go from there.

Edit: Ctrl+Shift+T > Type Name > Numeric pad +

This is using Resharper

Answer (score 1):

The Solution Navigator tab from [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/) can do this. Type something in the search box to narrow the display, and then multi-select, right-click, "Open" the things you're interested in. The search isn't as good as ReSharper's (it doesn't understand CamelCase, for example), but it works.

Answer (score 0):

How about using [Visual Studio's built-in macro recording/scripting/playback functionality](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b4c73967%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to repeat the command?